# How can I open DTS file in GOM player?

Tags: gom-player

DTS files are [encoded audio files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transformation_Services). I was wondering how to play a movie and use such file as the audio chanell.

Comment: DTS have nothing to do you your link (which is about Data Transformation Services). The correct is Digital Theater Systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTS_(company)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing the appropriate codec for DTS files?

http://player.gomlab.com/eng/codec/success.gom?intCodec=205